# Performance about the check() in Z3 for Java

Tags: java, performance, z3

I am using Z3 for Java to check satisfiability on terms with uninterpreted functions such as (type(o)>1 or type(p)<1). I am running into a performance issue caused by the check() function. For instance, it takes 6 ms to run solver.check() for a very simple constraint(type(o)>2 and type(o)=1).

```
        FuncDecl typeFun = ctx.MkFuncDecl("type", ctx.IntSort(), ctx.IntSort());        
        Expr o = ctx.MkConst("o", ctx.IntSort());
        //type(o)
        IntExpr to = (IntExpr)typeFun.Apply(o);
        //type(o)=1
        BoolExpr subExpr1 = ctx.MkEq(to, ctx.MkInt("1"));   
        //type(o)>2    
        BoolExpr subExpr2 = ctx.MkGt(to, ctx.MkInt("2"));  
        //type(o)>2 and type(o)=1
        BoolExpr expr = ctx.MkAnd(new BoolExpr[] { subExpr1, subExpr2 });

        solver.Assert(expr);
        //this step will take 6 ms.
        solver.check();
```

Given that the size of actual constraints in my project is much bigger(But each term is very simple such as type(o1)=1, type(o2)>1, etc) than this example and there are billions of such constraint need to resolve:
1. Is the performance of check() supposed to be like this?
2. If the answer to 1 is Yes, is there any other alternative way to bypass the performance issue?

Thanks in advance.

@ChristophWintersteiger:
I think a large portion of constraints in my system should be SAT. I am implementing a pointer analysis for Java and I am using Z3 to resolve the potential targets of virtual calls in a bottom-up way. Suppose I have a virtual callsite v.foo() and this callsite may invoke different methods based on the dynamic type of v. So for each callee foo(), I will introduce a constraint type(o) = T where o is the points-to set of receiver v and T is the class that declares foo. The constraint means that v.foo() can invoke method foo() in T when one of its dynamic points-to set has a type of T. All the constraint in my current system is some linear arithmetic with only one uninterpreted function "type(o)". But since I am analyzing the callgraph in a bottom-up manner, the constraint related to each virtual callsite can be expanded util the analysis reaches the root level and all the points-to targets of receivers have been resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

6ms sounds pretty fast to me. Why is this too slow?

`solver.check()` calls out to a native .dll/.so, so there is quite a bit of overhead involved before the call can be executed. Once `.check()` returns, there is another bit of overhead in checking the result for errors. So, it might well take 6ms simply because the application is using the Java API.

If the application is performance critical to such a high degree, then there might be no way around using the C API, because all the other APIs incur some non-zero overhead.

Addendum: I've done some profiling of the following simple kind:

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
int i = 0;
for (; i < 10000; i++) {                                
    status = solver.check();
}
long elapsedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
```

which takes about 22 seconds to run. The default solver that gets invoked here does indeed exhibit suboptimal performance on this particular instance. We can force Z3 to fall back to an older solver by adding the `ignore_solver1` option (or by using push/pop commands), i.e., setting it up as follows:

```
Solver solver = ctx.mkSolver();
Params solver_params = ctx.mkParams();
solver_params.add("ignore_solver1", true);
solver.setParameters(solver_params);
```

Solving the same problem 10k times now takes ~100ms (I get 9us/check).

The solver which gets invoked on these commands also supports incremental solving, so we can add push/pop commands almost for free:

```
for (; i < 10000; i++) {
    solver.push();
    status = solver.check();
    solver.pop();
}
```

which increases the runtime for 10k checks to ~120ms. Now, moving `solver.add(expr)` into this loop increases the runtime considerably, i.e., for this:

```
for (; i < 10000; i++) {
    solver.push();
    solver.add(expr);
    status = solver.check();
    solver.pop();
}
```

I get a runtime of ~275ms, i.e., close to double what we had before. Thus, at this point, the time required for expression construction/adding is of the same order of magnitude as the solving time. At this point, the bottleneck is indeed the Java API.

I should perhaps add that I only tried the example provided in the question. It may very well be the case that on a slightly different example the solvers behave differently and adding the `ignore_solver1` option will behave worse.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Java's native interop mechanism but it surely does not take 6ms to make a call. A .NET PInvoke for check would take maybe 100 instructions(?). Java will not lag far behind.

Comment: That may be true for a single call. For every single call to the Z3 API there is at least one more that follows (to check for errors), and for complex objects there will be another series of calls to find out what Java should cast an AST* to. The Java API (or the others like .NET, Python) are not built for raw performance in every single call.

Comment: @ChristophWintersteiger: Thanks. But 6ms for this simple constraint is really a big deal to my current system, especially we need to invoke the solver billion times in one typical benchmark. Since the whole system is implemented in Java, it's hard for me to switch it to c version.

Comment: I see, can you describe in more detail what those constraints look like and why you expect them to be solved so quickly? The example that's given here is unsatisfiable; do you expect most of those problems to be unsatisfiable? The example is also given in .NET API syntax; which of them are you actually using? Do you always have uninterpreted functions in those problems and if so how many? Is it always over integers or do you sometimes combine theories?

Comment: I've added some more profiling information to the question, could you check whether that solution works for more than just this particular example of constraints?

Comment: @ChristophWintersteiger:Thank you so much for the profiling information. I will test it in my current system and get back to you shortly.

Comment: @ChristophWintersteiger: I haven't used .NET API before but the example in my question is indeed using Java API:-).

Comment: In that case it may be an older version, it might be worth updating. E.g., all the Mk... functions have been renamed to mk... for consistency with Java and other libraries.

Comment: @ChristophWintersteiger I built it from source("unstable branch") based on Leonardo's blog: http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/8bfbdf1e680d#README Is this the older version?

Comment: @ChristophWintersteiger: I replied your previous question about the constraint in my current system in the original question.

Comment: @ChristophWintersteiger: I did the same profiling as you and it still takes 22s to solve the constraint 10,000 times even if I added "ignore_solver1". Is that because I am using an old version? The solving time reduces to 55ms when I added "push and pop" in the for-loop. I am a bit confused.

Comment: This could indeed be caused by the old version, because the parameter setting infrastructure has changed, so depending on how old your version is, the parameter might be called slightly different, or not be there at all. push/pop also forces it to use the faster solver though.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using custom tactics. The default solver uses quite an extensive portfolio of algorithms (I believe). Try using a simple tactic without preprocessing like `MkTactic("smt")`.

Comment: That's correct, but "smt" is itself a very complex tactic and likely to perform worse without preprocessing. Instead, if the problem can be transformed down to an easier class of problems, it may be possible to solve them using only preprocessors, but this is not necessarily always possible.

Comment: @usr:That's very helpful. I switched from solver.check() to a simple tactic like MkTactic("smt"). It takes 1.5ms compared to previous 6ms. Can we do better?

Comment: @YuFeng I usually grep the Z3 source code to find out what the tactics are made of. Try looking into some of the linear integer arithmetic (LIA) logics. The logics usually construct a complex tactic. That reveals what makes the work. Look into qflia_tactic.cpp. Also try making a solver for the "QF_LIA" logic. I believe your formula is in that logic.